# What is the scheme syntax to import modules (guile especially)?

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

How to import modules in Scheme (guile especially)?

How to create a module and import it in another script in scheme? How should I compile the script when I import a module, what are the command-line arguments that has to be passed? How to import the module if it is in another directory?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Modules.html#Modules

Comment: I created a module test_module.scm (http://paste.lisp.org/display/319117) and a script use_module.scm (http://paste.lisp.org/display/319118). Both module and the script are in the same directory. I tried to run the script with this command "guile use_module.scm". I get this error http://paste.lisp.org/display/319119 , for all I can understand the script is not able access the module. Please help.

Comment: Well I got help from the guys from the IRC and I learnt how its done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets create a module *test_module.scm* with the following code in it and its location being */some/dir*,

```
(define-module (test_module)
    #: export (square
               cube))

(define (square a)
    (* a a))
(define (cube a)
    (* a a a))
```

Here we have created a module using the syntax:

```
(define-module (name-of-the-module)
    #: export (function1-to-be-exported
               function2-to-be-exported))
;; rest of the code goes here for example: function1-to-be-exported
```

Now lets create a script that imports the module that we created named use_module.scm with this code in it, located in the current directory.

```
(use-modules (test_module))
(format #t "~a\n" (square 12))
```

Here we have used module using the syntax:

```
(use-modules (name-of-the-module))
;; now all the functions that were exported from the 
;; module will be available here for our use
```

Now lets come to the compiling part, we have to set GUILE_LOAD_PATH to the location */some/dir* and then compile the script.

Now lets assume that both test_module.scm and use_module.scm are in the same directory, then do this:

```
$ GUILE_LOAD_PATH=. guile use_module.scm
```

but generally do this if the module is present in */some/dir*:

```
$ GUILE_LOAD_PATH=/some/dir guile code.scm
```

p.s. The easier way to do this would be to write the script that uses *add-to-load-path* telling guile the location of the module. Now we can compile without worrying about the environment variables.

```
(add-to-load-path "/some/dir")
(use-modules (name-of-the-module))
;; rest of the code
```